# Best way to break apart long string using redshift SQL (included in question)?

Tags: python, sql, string, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

looking for the best way to break apart this blob of information into columns

```
DATE
AMOUNT
TYPE
UNDISCLOSED
INVESTORS
INVESTORS WEBSITES 

[{'date': 'Mon Aug 07 00:00:00 UTC 2004', 'amount': '1900000', 'type': 'Series D', 'undisclosed': 'false', 'investor': [{'name': 'Jobius Venture', 'website': 'jobiusvc.com'}]}, {'date': 'Tues July 06 00:00:00 UTC 2010', 'amount': '12000000000', 'type': 'Series A1', 'undisclosed': 'false', 'investor': [{'name': 'Fatthead Partners', 'website': 'fpartnazs.com'}, {'name': 'Jobius Venture', 'website': 'jobiusvc.com'}, {'name': 'Pista Pentures ', 'website': 'pisptavc.com'}]}, {'date': 'Sat Jun 01 00:00:00 UTC 2015', 'amount': '10000000000', 'type': 'Series X', 'undisclosed': 'false', 'investor': [{'name': 'Fatthead Partners', 'website': 'fpartnazs.com'}, {'name': 'Jobius Venture', 'website': 'jobiusvc.com'}, {'name': 'Pista Pentures', 'website': 'vistavc.com'}]}, {'date': 'Sun Aug 31 00:00:00 UTC 2015', 'amount': '3913000', 'type': 'Unknown', 'undisclosed': 'false'}, {'date': 'Mon Aug 12 00:00:00 UTC 2023', 'amount': '40000', 'type': 'Series D34', 'undisclosed': 'false', 'investor': [{'name': 'Fatthead Partners', 'website': 'fpartnazs.com'}, {'name': 'Jobius Venture', 'website': 'jobiusvc.com'}]}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your output is *almost* in JSON format.

For JSON, you could use: [JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT Function - Amazon Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/JSON_EXTRACT_PATH_TEXT.html)

**However,** it seems that the quotation marks are not standard JSON. It should use double-quotes (`"`) in JSON, not single quotes (`'`).

Also, the string appears to start with a List (`[...]`), which makes it incompatible with the JSON functions. A JSON object would normally be in `{..}` braces.

The output looks more like it **came from a Python program**. If so, and you have access to the Python program, it would be better to have it output in correct JSON format, so that you could use the above function. (Or just output the fields you actually want.)

You could write a Python [User-Defined Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/user-defined-functions.html) to do the conversion, such as:

```sql
create or replace function f_parse (str varchar(2000))
  returns varchar
stable
as $$
  return eval(str)[0]['date']
$$ language plpythonu;
```

Then:

```
select f_parse(s) from table
```

Results in: `Mon Aug 07 00:00:00 UTC 2004`

However, it appears that multiple records are in that one line, so I really suggest that you **get a better version of the input data** rather than trying to parse that line.